# Attach a content Database

Tags: content-database

I'm trying to attach a content Database and
I managed with the following command:

```
PS C:\temp> Mount-SPContentDatabase "Wss_ContentBack" -DatabaseServer "MYSQLSERVER\INSTANCE" -WebApplication http://myurl:8030 -AssignNewDatabaseId
```

but If I go to http://myurl:8030 my site collection is not there.
I get error 404

I've tried creating site collection after mounting the content database but still I don't see my sites.

What else should I do?

Comment: You're using -assignnewdatabaseid. Is this database already attached under a different name?

Comment: the database come from a sql server restore from another site collection. I used -AssignNewDatabaseId because if didn't I got an error saying that I should use that parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you got an error without using `-AssignNewDatabaseId`, that means a copy of that database is already attached to the farm. You cannot attach two content databases with the same Site Collections contained within it to the farm.

In order to restore, you either need to perform an unattached content database restore, or attach this content database backup to another farm and use `Backup-SPSite` on the Site Collection, then `Restore-SPSite` on the farm you want to restore the Site Collection to.

Comment: so not even if they are in two different web application2?

Comment: That is correct. The Site Collection GUID must be unique in the farm.